# SSIS Expression to get last day of the month given YYYYMM

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to figure out how to get the last day of the month given with a SSIS Expression.

I receive the column as an Integer, then added a Data Conversion step to convert the YYYMM to a date format.
Then on derived column, my expression is:

`REPLACE((DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("D",-(DAY(DATEADD("M",1,[Copy of MONTH]))),DATEADD("M",1,[Copy of MONTH])),"-","")`

And on final table I am getting the value 24520504.

Example: I am getting the value for the derived column from an .xls file. 
On that file, I use the column MONTH and it is an Integer (example: 201711).
On the final table it is an Integer too, but it has the last day from 201711 (example: 20171131)

EDIT: After your help, I reformulate my expression but I still get an error:

```
REPLACE((DT_STR,10,1252)DATEADD("d",-1,DATEADD("m",1,(DT_DBDATE)(DT_STR,6,1252)[MONTH])),"-","")
```

Comment: What do you mean "you receive column as an integer"? Are you saying you aren't storing dates as a date? Actual sample data and expected results (more than 1 sample) would help here.

Comment: Yes, I am storing dates as Integer. editted.

Comment: Do you want to return last month date as integer?

Comment: @Zhorov the last day of the month given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this column is being input to the Derived column as a `DT_DBDATE` date type, the following expression will get the last day of the month.  This expression essentially parses out the year and month first, uses these to build a new date by adding one month to this date (now in the next month), and then subtracts one day, which is the last `DATEADD` functions role, and then returns the date back to the same month, but now on the last day.  Finally, the outer `DAY` function returns the day.

```
DAY(DATEADD("day",-1,DATEADD("month",1,(DT_DBDATE)((DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR((DT_DBDATE)YourDateColumn) + "-" + RIGHT((DT_STR,2,1252)MONTH((DT_DBDATE)YourDateColumn),2) + "-01"))))
```

**Update:**

For the `DT_R8` data type that stores the date using the YYYYDD format, use the following expression to return the last day of the month.

```
  DAY(DATEADD("day",-1,DATEADD("month",1,(DT_DBDATE)SUBSTRING((DT_STR,12,1252)LEFT((DT_STR,8,1252)YourDateColumn,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING((DT_STR,8,1252)YourDateColumn,5,2) + "-01",1,12))))
```

Comment: Hello, for october, this expression is returning 30... I guess it should return 31.

Comment: The data type fed into this column is DT_DBDATE, with no other modifications after it's converted to this format, right?  I've tested this with October and the output was 31.

Comment: It is not DT_DBDATE, it is DT_R8

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the DT_R8 data type.

Comment: Yup, it works! But can you explain why you use LEFT there?

Comment: Good to hear, the LEFT function extracts the year part.

Answer (score 0):

where are you starting (this will return last date of month in date format)?

in SQL:

```
declare @YYYYMM as int = 201811
select dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,cast(cast(@YYYYMM as varchar(6))+'01' as date)))
```

This will take it all the way to int:

```
declare @YYYYMM as int = 201811
select cast(replace(cast(dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,cast(cast(@YYYYMM as varchar(6))+'01' as date))) as varchar(10)),'-','') as int)
```

In SSIS:

it's similar. I don't have a way to confirm it right now though. I'll edit later.

Comment: Not sure that'll work. Pretty sure the value is `201711` not `'201711'`, thus `201711+'01' = 201812`, which won't cast to a `date`.

Comment: i've tested this in SSMS.

Comment: I am not having much difficult to translate to t-sql, my problem is the ssis expression.

Comment: @KeithL yes, it'll work now that you have wrapped it in a `cast`: `cast({expression} as varchar(6))`. Previously is was still an `int` and `'201711' + '01' != 201711 + '01'`.

Comment: I got now: REPLACE((DT_STR,10,1252)DATEADD("d",-1,DATEADD("m",1,(DT_DBDATE)(DT_STR,6,1252)[MÊS])),"-",""), but I am getting an error:

[Derived Column [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[PERIODO_FINAL]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

this should work...

```
periodo ='201803'

DATEADD("day",-1,DATEADD("month",1,(DT_DBDATE)((DT_STR,4,1252)LEFT(period,4) + "-" + RIGHT(period,2) + "-01")))
```